# adb backup issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, adb

I'm creating a batch file to automate an adb backup, but the backup argument is creating a folder instead of a file, the batch code is:

```
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f %%a in ('adb get-serialno') do set device=%%a
adb backup -f "backup\%device%_%mydate%.ab" -apk -shared -all -system
```

This creates a folder with the device name and date, not a file.

Current adb.exe version:

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
Revision eac51f2bb6a8-android
```

Comment: Did you try using the full path instead of the relative path?

Comment: Yep, but I think that its a adb problem, because a tried without problems on version 1.0.31.

Comment: For the moment with the last revision: 09a0d98bebce works well...